# Transition depending on previous route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have one layout and multiple pages I would like to set different(2) transition depending on the previous route one bounceInUp and one bounceInDown 
For now, only one working using :

```
.page-enter-active {
    animation: bounceInUp 1.5s ease-out both;
}
.page-leave-active {
    animation: acrossOut 0.65s ease-in both;
}
```

I don't know how to set a second transition
How do I dynamically change it?

thanks

Comment: If you have access to you’re route parameters you could bind a class to the transition element depending on the parameter. :class=“{“page-enter-active”: $route.someparam == “some condition”}”

Comment: Nuxt.js automatically assign the class on transition but i have access to routes params. i am digging threw nuxt.js code to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the transition key in you page as a function.

```
export default {
  transition (to, from) {
    if (from is something) return 'bounceInUp'
    //or a ternary
    return +to.query.page < +from.query.page ? 'bounceInUp' : 'bounceInDown'
  }
}
```

You can see it in the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition#function)

Comment: Thank you so much i had hard time to understand it but i digged a bit more thaks to your comment.